# btrfs subvolume quota and free space for samba share

Tags: linux, filesystems, samba, btrfs, quota

My btrfs filesystem is mounted under `/mnt/btrfs`. I then created a subvolume `/mnt/btrfs/sv` and enabled quotas. After that I set the quota to 10G with `btrfs qgroup limit -e 10G /mnt/btrfs/sv` and exported the subvolume as a samba share to be used on a Windows machine. `btrfs qgroup show -pcre /mnt/btrfs/` shows that everything is fine.

The problem I am facing is, that

1. the subvolume is not showing up with `df`
2. when mounted to another place, `df` shows the available free space of `/mnt/btrfs`
3. for 1) and 2) Windows shows the available space of `/mnt/btrfs` and not the set quota

What I am missing here?